# Many Errors in LogCat on Android Device

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, device, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a Nexus 4 with Android 6.0 and i have connected it in Developer Mode to my Android Studio to see what the Log-File output looks like. The LogCat sends many errors:

```
1. 02-25 09:15:46.787 548-623/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine CMD_START_SCAN source -2 txSuccessRate=0,00 rxSuccessRate=0,00 targetRoamBSSID=any RSSI=-53
2. 02-25 09:15:46.787 548-623/? E/WifiStateMachine: WifiStateMachine L2Connected CMD_START_SCAN source -2 226, 227 -> obsolete
3. 02-25 09:15:36.955 3609-3609/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
4. 02-25 09:15:28.154 195-218/? E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK: Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
5. 02-25 09:15:27.479 548-623/? E/WifiStateMachine: cancelDelayedScan -> 227
6. 02-25 09:15:27.483 548-623/? E/native: do suspend true
7. 02-25 09:14:42.632 188-31249/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -8
8. 02-25 09:16:36.436 1596-1596/? E/ctxmgr: [PowerConnectionProducer]Could not write powerInfo=Plug state: 2 BatteryLevel: 0.85, status=Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 7503, resolution=null}
```

What are all these errors? They are appearing over and over again in different orders and are appearing independent from each other.

The Error:

```
02-25 09:18:36.981 3609-3609/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Appears each 10 seconds even when there is no app active and all background proceses of all apps are killed.

Comment: are you passing data ?

Comment: Im doing nothing with the phone. All i do is reading the log output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many apps running the background log the actions being done. Some of them also raises errors. `WifiStateMachine` gives data about your Wifi connection, `PowerConnectionProducer` gives data about your battery and so on. You will get errors similar to these on all devices.

This is no reason to worry, unless you have an error associated with your own app.

Answer (score 1):

**These are system logs**,which you see after connecting your device.

This Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process. Consequently this exception can be thrown when there are many transactions in progress.

Please refer to [TransactionTooLarge](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)